# Changing String Variable on Second View Gives Error

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, string, nsstring

When trying to send a value from my JSON file to a string in another ViewController, I end up getting this error:

```
2013-08-05 08:15:50.597 AHMC[11304:70b] -[UINavigationController setSessionKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x898d3f0
2013-08-05 08:15:50.600 AHMC[11304:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController setSessionKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x898d3f0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0172eed4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x014af8b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x017cbb83 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0171f1fb ___forwarding___ + 1019
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0171edde _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   AHMC                                0x00008013 -[LoginViewController loginAction:] + 963
    6   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x014c1874 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
    7   UIKit                               0x0023c968 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 108
    8   UIKit                               0x0023c8f4 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
    9   UIKit                               0x00330581 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
    10  UIKit                               0x00330944 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 577
    11  UIKit                               0x0032fbf3 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 641
    12  UIKit                               0x0027956d -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 852
    13  UIKit                               0x0027a172 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1134
    14  UIKit                               0x0024df06 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
    15  UIKit                               0x00238b0f _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 11421
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x016b817f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x016b7b0b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x016d4bde __CFRunLoopRun + 910
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x016d4403 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x016d421b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x03697a37 GSEventRunModal + 192
    22  GraphicsServices                    0x0369785e GSEventRun + 104
    23  UIKit                               0x0023b6bb UIApplicationMain + 1225
    24  AHMC                                0x00009d8d main + 141
    25  libdyld.dylib                       0x01d6b70d start + 1
    26  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Here is the code that sends the variable's new value to the variable on the next view controller.

```
FirstViewController *dash = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"dashboard"];

    dash.sessionKey = [jsonArray objectForKey:@"new_session_key"];
```

And I verify that the value of new_session_key is something by testing with NSLog and it is "262040c7c199e59abfe78009f3ecd8".

And yes I created the variables in the second view's header file:

```
 @interface FirstViewController : UIViewController
{
    NSString *sessionKey;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *sessionKey;
```

Please assist as to why I am getting this error.

Comment: The retured value getting from [jsonArray objectForKey:@"new_session_key"] is an string ?

Comment: Have you synthesized sessionKey in .m file ?

Comment: `-[UINavigationController setSessionKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x898d3f0` Did you enter the subclass `FirstViewController` in Interface Builder?

Comment: you need to syntesize first and then you can acess that properties to next view controller.....

Comment: Can't seem to synthesize it, it doesn't recognize the variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you look the 1st line of the error carefully,

`-[UINavigationController setSessionKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x898d3f0`

So instead of calling FirstViewController's sessionKey property, its trying to call it for UINavigationController and which is the reason for your crash.

I would ask you to check the Storyboard ID for FirstViewController... I believe you are using the Storyboard ID for UINavigationController => "dashboard"

I hope it helps to solve the crash

Comment: I do not understand what you wrote at all... well, how to fix it.

Comment: okie.. could you open your storyboard and select the viewcontroller for FirstViewController. check the storyboard id for it. Copy that storyboard id and replace it with "dashboard" in the following code

`FirstViewController *dash = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"dashboard"];`

Comment: And make sure that on the right (Utilities) in the third tab (Identity Inspector) you entered as your Custom Class `FirstViewController`